# Vue3, Render parent div only if slot inside of it has content

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to render a header only if there's a text or a populated slot inside of it.

I tried:

```
<div
            class="flex py-sm px-md w-full align-middle rounded-t-xl"
            v-if="props.title || $slots.header"
            :class="[`bg-${props.headerColor}`]"
        >
            <p class="text-bo-xl font-bold" :class="`text-${props.titleTextColor}`">
                {{ props.title }}
            </p>
            <slot name="header"></slot>
        </div>
```

But the div renders anyway, even if the slot is empty. I think it considers the slot present even if it's not populated.

Any ideas?

Comment: not sure, but if i remember correctly its $slots.default() or $slots.namedSlot() and therefor $slot.nameSlot always returns a truthy value. you may give `v-if="props.title || ($slots.header && $slots.header())"` a try.

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work out for me, the behavior is the same as before.

Comment: Did you try with `v-if="$slots.header"` ?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: What does logging this.$slots give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for the late response. If I utilize `computed()` it seems to work:

```js
<template>
  <section>
    <h4>lorem</h4>
    <div v-if="hasHeaderSlot">
      <h2>ipsum</h2>
      <slot name="header"></slot>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { computed } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup(_, { slots }) {
    const hasHeaderSlot = computed(() => slots.header && slots.header());

    return {
      hasHeaderSlot,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I hope this helps. With best regards